# Exibir o resultado de um COUNT no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

O codigo PHP esta assim:

```
$con = new PDO(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA);
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM quiz;");
        $sql->execute();
        $n = $sql->fetchObject();
```

E o codigo HTML está assim:

```
<h1>0<?= print $n->COUNT(id);?></h1>
```

e o erro que aparece:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::COUNT() in ............

alguém poderia me mostrar o erro ?

Comment: pq vc n dá um alias para o count essa chamada `print $n->COUNT(id);` está pra de estranha. Chama de total por exemplo ;)

Comment: Mas como seria a maneira certa de exibir o resultado do COUNT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao tentar ler um campo como esse `$n->COUNT(id);` o php entende que você está chamando um método chamado `count()` e passado a constante `id` para ele porém esse método não existe em um objeto `PDOStatement`.

A solução é dar uma alias para o campo.

Mude:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM quiz
```

Para:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM quiz
```

No php chame a propriedade normalmente

```
<h1>0<?= print $n->total;?></h1>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado estou aprendendo ainda, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma;

```
try {         
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM quiz");
        $stmt->execute(); 

        while ($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             echo  "<label>Total:</b> ".$linha['total']."<label>";
           }
        } catch (PDOException $e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua query tem assim:

> `$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM quiz;");`

Experimente acrescentar o `AS id`:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM quiz;");
```

E quando for para exibir, simplesmente mostre como se fosse uma variavél normal da sua base de dados.

Ficará algo parecido ao que o [Rafa_Developer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302650/exibir-o-resultado-de-um-count-no-banco-de-dados) e o [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302650/exibir-o-resultado-de-um-count-no-banco-de-dados) escreveu.

Comment: Valeu mano, ajudou muito.